# WordPress editor made in React?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I have added 'React Developer Tools' as Chrome extension in my browser which shows me which all sites are using ReactJS. While writing a post today, I noticed that the extension shows my WordPress editor is using the production build of React.

[Extension shows the editor is made in React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYowq.png)

I quickly visited my WordPress site but the extension doesn't trigger there.

[Actual WordPress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QCEw.png)

So what is happening here? Is this just a bug in the extension? I know that you can use WordPress as a headless CMS in React but that is certainly not the case here.

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug? Just because the thing in which you create the site uses React, it doesn't necessarily mean the site thus created uses it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The question is - is WordPress editor really made in React or it's a fault of my extension? WordPress itself is a big platform (probably the largest?!) written in PHP, why would they use ReactJS then?

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/

Comment: @jonrsharpe https://ibb.co/F0ktZZj I understand but the editor that I am using is the old one. I have not switched to the new Gutenberg editor. If they were using the same tech stack previously too then it would make sense. I think that's the case. Anyway, thank you so much! It made things clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your wordpress editor just uses a component written with react that is not required on the website (maybe the editor itself?).

It's not uncommon practice. For example, if you add "Facebook comment plugin" on your website, it will add react on the background. If you have the react extension enabled, it will tell you that react has been found, even if it's used just for a little part of the website.

Moreover, I presume your readers are not meant to use the editor, so it make sense that they do not have to download it since is not required for them.

To confirm that's the case, you can open chrome dev tools and use the "`network`" - it would tell you exactly what resources have been requested by the current page.

Comment: You are right! I looked through the requested files in the "network" tab and it seems that WordPress editor does use multiple components made in React. It skipped my mind that even if a single component is using React, the extension would show it to be so. The whole website need not be written in React. Also, your guess was spot on. I found some react modules in the post-editor script - https://ibb.co/9rXHs0j

Answer (score 0):

React is included at the core of WordPress and obviously, it embeds the production build.

The following is not the cleanest solution but is useful for theme development. It works by replacing the production build for the development one at enqueuing time. You may check for React version that your WordPress installation is using.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
$replace = [
    'react' => 'https://unpkg.com/react@16.9.0/umd/react.development.js',
    'react-dom' => 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.9.0/umd/react-dom.development.js'
];
if (!array_key_exists($handle, $replace)) return $tag;
$newTag = str_replace($src, $replace[$handle], $tag);
$newTag = str_replace('><', ' crossorigin><', $tag);
return wp_get_environment_type() === 'development'
    ? $newTag
    : $tag; 
}, 10, 3 );
```

Make sure you have set the environment to 'development' in wp-config.php.

```
define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'development' );
```